# While uploading image into server after converting it into base 64 format. Image view is loading the same old Image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64

I have to convert an Image into base 64 and upload user_image into server using camera.  After uploading into server what I have to show is in ImageView.

After upload into server the image is not changing.  While I am closing the app and opening again then only it is changing the image.

```
public void onCropImageClick() 
{ 
    Bitmap cropped = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(550, 550); 
    if (cropped != null) 
        //this is imageView 
        user_imageView.setImageBitmap(cropped); 

    //here i am converting image to base64 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new 
    ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
    base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), 0);
    // here I am upload image into server
    sendImageUrl(base64Image);
} 

public void sendImageUrl(String base64Image) {
    // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    System.out.println("Image profile came here:4  sendImageUrl");
    uploadImage(base64Image);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your issue. Include the code that does not work.

Comment: Look here for information on how to format your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution for this .
i was a  problem of Glide and Picasso image loader .

We need clear Cache every time before setting image into image view .

**add this before adding image**

```
 CacheClearAsyncTask task = new CacheClearAsyncTask();
                        task.execute();



class CacheClearAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearDiskCache();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearMemory();
        }
    }
```